# convert to JSON

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am developing a health app by accessing health data from apple's healthkit. I can access the Blood Pressure and BMI data.

I want the send this data back to my JS file in JSON format.

Required format is something like this

```
{   "items" : [
    {
      "endDate" : "2020-01-25",
      "BloodPressure" : "122/65",
      "startDate" : "2020-01-25"
    },
    {
      "endDate" : "2020-01-25",
      "BMI" : "24.6",
      "startDate" : "2020-01-25"
    }   ] }
```

My BP and BMI queries are:

```
func getBloodPressure(_ resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {
    var value : Any = ""
    guard let type = HKQuantityType.correlationType(forIdentifier: HKCorrelationTypeIdentifier.bloodPressure),
                let systolicType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodPressureSystolic),
                let diastolicType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bloodPressureDiastolic) else {

                    return
            }
         let now = Date()
         let startDate = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: now)
         let endDate = now
         let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startDate, end: endDate, options: .strictStartDate)

            let sampleQuery = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: type, predicate: predicate, limit: 0, sortDescriptors: nil) { (sampleQuery, results, error) in
                if let dataList = results as? [HKCorrelation] {
                    for data in dataList
                    {
                        if let data1 = data.objects(for: systolicType).first as? HKQuantitySample,
                            let data2 = data.objects(for: diastolicType).first as? HKQuantitySample {

                            let value1 = data1.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.millimeterOfMercury())
                            let value2 = data2.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.millimeterOfMercury())
                            value = "\(value1) / \(value2)"
                            resolve(value)
                        }}}}
                   healthStore.execute(sampleQuery)
      }
```

```
 @objc
  func getBMI(_ resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {
    let bodyMassType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.bodyMassIndex)
    let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: bodyMassType!, predicate: nil, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: nil) { (query, results, error) in
                if let result = results?.first as? HKQuantitySample {
                  let bodyMassIndex = result.quantity.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())
                    print("BMI in xcode",bodyMassIndex, result.endDate)
                  resolve(bodyMassIndex)
                    return
                }}
       healthStore.execute(query)
      }
```

Now I have created 2 structures:

```
struct BloodPressureItem: Codable {
        let endDate: String?
        let BloodPressure: String?
        let startDate: String?
    }

struct BodyMassIndexItem: Codable {
        let endDate: String?
        let BMI: String?
        let startDate: String?
    }
```

Next I appended the objects with my data.

```
let jsonData = BloodPressureItem.init(endDate: end, Bloodpressure: String(value), startDate: start)
let jsonData = BodyMassIndexItem.init(endDate: end, BMI: String(bodyMassIndex), startDate: start)
```

Result I got is

```
BloodPressureItem(endDate: Optional("2021-01-25 07:43:27 +0000"), BloodPressure: Optional("122.0/65.0"), startDate: Optional("2021-01-24 07:43:27 +0000"))

BodyMassIndexItem(endDate: Optional("2021-01-25 07:43:27 +0000"), BMI: Optional("24.6"), startDate: Optional("2021-01-24 07:43:27 +0000"))
```

Next how do I convert this into my required format?

**UPDATE:**

```
{   "items" : [
    “BloodPressure:” {
      "endDate" : "2020-01-25",
      “Value” : "122/65",
      "startDate" : "2020-01-25"
    },
   “BMI:” {
      "endDate" : "2020-01-25",
      “Value” : "24.6",
      "startDate" : "2020-01-25"
    }   ] }
```

Comment: It's quite laborious to encode a heterogenous array with `Encodable`. I'd prefer `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: I would use enums and depending on the key use one or the other. Enums are amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a third struct that holds the other two

```
struct HealthData: Codable {
    let bloodPressure: BloodPressureItem
    let bmi: BodyMassIndexItem
}
```

and then then encode an instance of this struct

```
let bloodPressure = BloodPressureItem.init(endDate: end, Bloodpressure: String(value), startDate: start)
let bmi = BodyMassIndexItem(endDate: end, BMI: String(bodyMassIndex), startDate: start)

let healthData = HealthData(bloodPressure: bloodPressureItem, bmi: bmiItem)

do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(healthData)
} catch { 
     //error handling
}
```

I have assumed you want to send one of each but otherwise you can simply change the properties to be arrays instead,

```
struct HealthData: Codable {
    let bloodPressureValues: [BloodPressureItem]
    let bmiValues: [BodyMassIndexItem]
}
```

---

In your code you have made everything optional and of type String, I would recommend to not use optional and instead the original types like

```
struct BloodPressureItem: Codable {
    let endDate: Date
    let BloodPressure: Double
    let startDate: Date
}
```

---

Another possible solution is to use a single custom type for all kind of data

```
enum HealthDataType: String, Codable {
    case bloodPressure
    case bmi
}
struct HealtDataItem: Codable {
    let endDate: Date
    let value: Double
    let startDate: Date
    let type: HealthDataType
}
```

and then add all objects to an array and encode the array

```
let bloodPressureItem = HealtDataItem(endDate: end, value: bloodPressureValue, startDate: start, type: .bloodPressure)
let bmiItem = HealtDataItem(endDate: end, value: bmiValue, startDate: start, type: .bmi)

let healthData = [bloodPressureItem, bmiItem]

do {
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(healthData)
} catch { 
     //error handling
}
```

Comment: The enum way is a superb approach. Thanks man it worked and it printed an array of objects. One last query if I want to move the HealthDataType outside the object (see the last part of my updated question) do I have to create a new object and append the HealthDataItem to it?

Comment: You could use a dictionary instead of an array but please respect that you’re only supposed to ask one question at a time

Answer (score 0):

I love enums and most definitely I would use an enum here to handle these polymorphic types. This way you can keep your data non-optional and avoid using `?` and `??` all over the place unnecessarily.

It will also be a good idea to store a `type` along with the data to easily decode

```
/// An enum that represents the polymorphic json object that will be stored/sent
enum HealthRecord: Encodable {
    case bmi(BodyMassIndexItem)
    case bloodPressure(BloodPressureItem)
    
    /// The type will be stored by the encoder to make easier decoding.
    private var type: HealthRecordType {
        switch self {
        case .bloodPressure: return .bloodPressure
        case .bmi: return .bmi
        }
    }
    
    /// Coding keys are used by the encoder/decoder
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        // Encode `type` for easier future decoding
        try container.encode(type, forKey: .type)
        
        // Encode the polymorphic type
        switch self {
        case .bmi(let bodyMassIndex):
            // Encode the contents of the BMI
            try bodyMassIndex.encode(to: encoder)
        case .bloodPressure(let bloodPressure):
            // Encode the contents of blood pressure
            try bloodPressure.encode(to: encoder)
        }
    }
}

/// A private enum used to tell us the type of health record this is (so we don't have to look at keys). This value will tell us how to decode the object in the future.
private enum HealthRecordType: String, Encodable {
    case bmi
    case bloodPressure
}

struct BodyMassIndexItem: Encodable {
    let endDate: String?
    let BloodPressure: String?
    let startDate: String?
}

struct BloodPressureItem: Encodable {
    let endDate: String?
    let BloodPressure: String?
    let startDate: String?
}
```

Couple of mentions:

1. You can encode dates using a dateEncodingStrategy (or other mechanisms)
2. You shouldn't make things optional if you know they are never optional
3. You can get the current date using Date()
4. I won't get into too much detail but I think stripping out the time from your date objects is risky. If you don't know what you're doing with dates, consider using an `RFC3339` or `ISO8601DateFormatter` date formatter instead: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter